# How to install Mockito into Eclipse using Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, mockito

I want to use Mockito in my Eclipse, and you can only install it through build programs such as maven or Gradle, I chose to use Gradle. I am a beginner in using Gradle, but I just need to install Mockito and be able to use it as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually "install" Mockito. You just add it to your dependency management system. Since you're using Gradle, all you have to do is add it to your `build.gradle` file. I'm assuming you've started with a blank Gradle project or something like that, which included a default `build.gradle` file.

Somewhere in that file you'll declare all your project dependencies:

`dependencies {
    // other dependencies will be here, just add the following line:
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19")
}`

You can find out Mockito's artifact/group ids and available versions here: http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=mockito

Comment: testCompile is deprecated and will throw an error for anyone stumbling on this